# Rails form that redirects to show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, search

I'm using Rails 4 and have a `Policy` model with a field `policy_number`.

I'd like to create a (search-like) form where you input a `policy_number` and it redirects you to that Policy's show page. I'm not sure how to go about this, should the form's action be `policy_path` or something?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd go with Ajax call...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem here is that the user is inputting the policy number in the search form, so you don't have access to it at the time the form is rendered. Without using JavaScript, you won't be able to go directly to the policy by policy number entered.

Here's a possible starting point, though. Create a `PolicySearchController` with an `index` method, add a route for it, and create a simple form.

*app/controllers/policy_search_controller.rb*

```
class PolicySearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    policy = Policy.where(policy_number: params[:policy_number]).first

    if policy.present?
      redirect_to policy
    else
      redirect_to :policies, alert: "No matching policy found."
    end
  end
end
```

*config/routes.rb*

```
resources :policy_search, only: :index
```

*app/views/policies/index.html.erb*

```
<%= form_tag policy_search_index_path, method: :get do -%>
  <%= text_field_tag :policy_number -%>
<% end -%>
```

Now you can iterate on this to add JavaScript, fuzzy matching, etc. if desired.

Comment: Does it have to be a new controller? i.e. can I just add a method to my existing one?

Comment: Sure, you could add it as a non-RESTful action to your existing controller.